# Flash installation issue Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu, flash

Every time I startup or reboot my PC I get the following notification that flash needs to be installed :

[image]

When I say "Ok" it starts the installation procedure but it stops and gives me the following error :

[image]

When I click on "Details" nothing happen (?!)

Any idea on how to get rid of this notification? It's not bothering very much but I don't know why it won't install it.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have flash installed? Run `sudo apt install flashplugin-installer` and see if it installs. If it did, did it remove the warning?

Comment: Mark, thank you for your reply! I get this message :

     W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/adobe-flashplugin_20160512.1.orig.tar.gz' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

Comment: This seems to be a bug in `apt`, here is the bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/1543280 Consider adding you details here, the more reports they get the faster it will get fixed. Unfortunately, I don't think there is anything anyone here can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some important info: after about twenty minutes, it will time out.  That's good because you can complete the Ubuntu Installation.  The installation will still be successful.

Next time, de-select "update packages while installing ubuntu (this will save you some time)".  Instead, run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` AFTER you have finished installing Ubuntu.

Also, if you are in a country/status or network that won't allow you to download flash player, then you should use VPN prior to attempting your flash player install.